# how to download all blob from a container where blob sits in sub directory style

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have blob files which sits under container in a sub-directory style,

- container name = log-test
- Year folder
- Month folder
- Date folder
- Hour folder

[image]

Through C# background job every hour I need to downloads all the blob files for that `Hour` folder.

Here in below code I am able to download `one` file with hard code path (Year/Month/Date/Hour/blob-name), but how to download all the blob file for current date/time hour?

```
 var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("conn-str");
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("log-test");

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("2021/08/11/01/log.txt");

        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(@"C:\Temp\Result.txt");
```

**Note: -
I tried this, but is this a performance issue? Can't I go directly to the actual HOUR folder?**

```
var blobItems = containerClient.GetBlobs().Where(blobItem => blobItem.Properties.LastModified != null 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Day == DateTime.UtcNow.Day 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Hour == DateTime.UtcNow.Hour)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var blob in blobItems)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync($"C:\\Temp\\{blob.Name.Replace('/','-')}");
        }
```

Comment: Note: - 
I tried this, but is this a performance issue? Can't I go directly to the actual HOUR folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code of yours

```
var blobItems = containerClient.GetBlobs().Where(blobItem => blobItem.Properties.LastModified != null 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Day == DateTime.UtcNow.Day 
                                                             && blobItem.Properties.LastModified.Value.Hour == DateTime.UtcNow.Hour)
            .ToList();
```

is not optimized as it lists all blobs in the container and then do the filtering on the client side.

The method you would want to use is [`BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetBlobsByHierarchy_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobTraits_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobStates_System_String_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and specify `Year/Month/Date/Hour/` as the value for the `prefix` parameter. You will then only get the blobs for that hour. Once you have that list, then you can download the blobs individually.