# how to download all blob from a container where blob is in sub directory style using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

The below code will download a particular blob by giving the blob name

```
import constants
import os
import tempfile
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print(temp_dir.name)
Local_path = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, constants.BLOB_NAME)


class AzureBlob:
    def __init__(self, CONNECTION_STRING, BLOB_CONTAINER,
                 BLOB_PATH, BLOB_NAME):
        self.blob_service_client = self.activate_blob_service()
        self.container_client = self.initialize_container()
        self.BLOB_CONTAINER = BLOB_CONTAINER
        self.CONNECTION_STRING = CONNECTION_STRING
        self.BLOB_PATH = BLOB_PATH
        self.BLOB_NAME = BLOB_NAME

        # Initialize a BlobServiceClient object

    def activate_blob_service(self):
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.CONNECTION_STRING)
        # print(self.CONNECTION_STRING)
        return self.blob_service_client

        # Initialize a container from its name

    def initialize_container(self):
        self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(self.BLOB_CONTAINER)
        # print(container_client)
        return self.container_client

        # Download Blob to local

    def download_file(self):
        with open(Local_path, 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(self.container_client.download_blob(os.path.join(self.BLOB_PATH, self.BLOB_NAME)).readall())
        return Local_path


# AzureBlob().download_file()
a = AzureBlob(constants.CONNECTION_STRING, constants.BLOB_CONTAINER,
              constants.BLOB_PATH, constants.BLOB_NAME)
```

What iam actualy trying to achieve is to download all blob from a container where blob is in sub directory. I will provide the directory path of the blob and i need all the information inside the directory to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the above requirement you can try the below workaround to download all the files from your container,

```
# download_blobs.py
# Python program to bulk download blob files from azure storage
# Uses latest python SDK() for Azure blob storage
# Requires python 3.6 or above
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings, ContainerClient
 
# IMPORTANT: Replace connection string with your storage account connection string
# Usually starts with DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;...
MY_CONNECTION_STRING = "REPLACE_THIS"
 
# Replace with blob container
MY_BLOB_CONTAINER = "myimages"
 
# Replace with the local folder where you want files to be downloaded
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "REPLACE_THIS"
 
class AzureBlobFileDownloader:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Intializing AzureBlobFileDownloader")
 
    # Initialize the connection to Azure storage account
    self.blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
    self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(MY_BLOB_CONTAINER)
 
 
  def save_blob(self,file_name,file_content):
    # Get full path to the file
    download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)
 
    # for nested blobs, create local path as well!
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
 
    with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
      file.write(file_content)
 
  def download_all_blobs_in_container(self):
    my_blobs = self.my_container.list_blobs()
    for blob in my_blobs:
      print(blob.name)
      bytes = self.my_container.get_blob_client(blob).download_blob().readall()
      self.save_blob(blob.name, bytes)
 
# Initialize class and upload files
azure_blob_file_downloader = AzureBlobFileDownloader()
azure_blob_file_downloader.download_all_blobs_in_container()
```

For more information please refer this [***blog post***](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/azure/how-to-download-blobs-from-azure-storage-using-python.html) & [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551608/how-to-download-all-blob-from-a-container-where-blob-sits-in-sub-directory-style)

Comment: thanks @AjayKumar. I saw this code already but,my scenario is to download from a given path. If i download all files from the container then there will lots of data.

Comment: Hi @Saravanan ,Could you please refer this [GitHub sample code](https://gist.github.com/brijrajsingh/35cd591c2ca90916b27742d52a3cf6ba)

Comment: Could you please also refer the so thread which i have attached in answer.Thanks